# How to Improve Iterating over Python Class

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, iteration, coding-style

I am working on a set of calculations for a number of loans in a portfolio.

I've created several classes in Python (I am using Jupyter notebook). The first class "PortfolioInput" includes static input values that apply to all loans in the portfolio. The next two "PortfolioAssumptionA" and "B" are tables of assumptions. Lastly, I intended to use the class "Loan" over and over for each loan in the portfolio.

I have some made-up methods in the Loan class, but I have about 10 of them, and as you see in the for loop, I need to bring in the methods multiple times to calculate something else as the output (say cf_output 1 and 2).

I am using xlwings to read in data from an excel file (with named ranges), and my portfolio includes about 3,000 loans. The calculations happening inside the for loop is in reality much longer.. although it works, it takes hours to complete. At the end of the loop, I use the outputs for my analysis...

Can anyone give me some advise on how to improve the for loop, or if I can improve the structures I am using here?
Specifically, the way I am using `portAsm_A = PortfolioAssumptionA().GetAssumptionA()` to use the table inside the class "Loan" and `results = AllLoans.apply(lambda x:Loan(*x), axis=1)` to instantiate class for all loans... I need help if this is even how you would do in Python. I appreciate your time in advance, anything will be so helpful!!!

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

class PortfolioInput:
    ClosingDate: str="12/1/2020"
    ReinvestmentPeriod: int = 6
    LastPeriod: int = 120

@dataclass
class PortfolioAssumptionA:
    def GetAssumptionA(self):
        assumption = wb.names['assumptionA'].refers_to_range.options(
            pd.DataFrame, header=1, expand='table').value
        return assumption
    
@dataclass
class PortfolioAssumptionB:
    def GetAssumptionB(self):
        assumption = wb.names['assumptionB'].refers_to_range.options(
            pd.DataFrame, header=1, expand='table').value
        return assumption

wb = xw.Book('filename.xlsx')
portAsm_A = PortfolioAssumptionA().GetAssumptionA()
portAsm_B = PortfolioAssumptionB().GetAssumptionB()

@dataclass
class Loan(PortfolioInput):
    LoanNumber: int
    LoanType: str
    BeginningBalance: float
    IntRate: float
    Flag: str
    State: str

    def CalculateSomething1(self) -> float:
        output = self.BeginningBal * self.IntRate
        return output

    def CalculateSomething2(self, rating) -> float:
        output = self.BeginningBal * portAsm_A.loc[:,rating][0]
        return output
    
    def CalculateSomething3(self, rating) -> float:
        output = self.CalculateSomething2() * portAsm_B.loc[:,rating][0]
        

AllLoans = pd.DataFrame(xw.Range('LoanTable').options(header=True).value) #total ~3000
results = AllLoans.apply(lambda x:Loan(*x), axis=1)

rating = ["A+", "A", "A-", "BBB+", "BBB", "BBB-", "BB+"]

cf_output1 = {key: {key: [] for key in results} for key in rating}
cf_output2 = {key: {key: [] for key in results} for key in rating}

for i in range(len(results)):
    row = results.loc[i]
    for r in rating:
        cf_output1[rating][i] = row.CalculateSomething1() * row.CalculateSomething2(rating)
        if row.BeginningBalance >= 10000:
            cf_output2[rating][i] = row.CalculateSomething3(rating)/100
        else: cf_output2[rating][i] = row.CalculateSomething3(rating) * self.IntRate
```

Edit: Here's what assumptionA looks like:

```
             A+  A    A-    BBB+    BBB BBB-    BB+
asusmptionA 0.5 0.45 0.4    0.35    0.3 0.25    0.2
```

And this is what Loans look like:

```
    LoanNumber LoanType BeginningBalance IntRate Flag State
0   1.0           A         10000.0       0.030    Y    MA
1   2.0           A         15000.0       0.020    Y    NY
2   3.0           A         9500.0        0.035    Y    NY
3   4.0           B         20000.0       0.210    N    NH
4   5.0           A         15850.0       0.340     Y   MD
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  Your post is far too broad, without supporting data.
You have to ask a *specific* question about your implementation; this is Stack Overflow, not Code Review.

Comment: @Prune thanks, I added some example data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could store the rating as part of the `Loan` class. This would mean you wouldn`t need to make the dicts to hold the ratings.